# Função para abrir a tela cheia (Fullscreen) No angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, javascript-eventos

Estou precisando q a minha tela abre cheia ... Quando eu dar um ng Serve pra aplicação ao rodar ela vem com um fullscreen. Alguém pode me dar uma dica de como fazer isso ?

Comment: É angular ou Angularjs? Que que isto funcione em Ionic ou browser no computador?

Answer (score -1):

Crie essa função:

```
function requestFullScreen(element) {
    // Supports most browsers and their versions.
    var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

    if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
        requestMethod.call(element);
    } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
        var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
        if (wscript !== null) {
            wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
        }
    }
}
```

e adicione a sua chamada, passando o elemento body como parametro em algum evento que o usuário possa interagir.

Por exemplo, no click de um botão com a frase "Clique aqui para Maximizar" ou no click do body(apenas exemplo):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function requestFullScreen(element) {
            // Supports most browsers and their versions.
            var requestMethod = element.requestFullScreen || element.webkitRequestFullScreen || element.mozRequestFullScreen || element.msRequestFullScreen;

            if (requestMethod) { // Native full screen.
                requestMethod.call(element);
            } else if (typeof window.ActiveXObject !== "undefined") { // Older IE.
                var wscript = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
                if (wscript !== null) {
                    wscript.SendKeys("{F11}");
                }
            }
        }

        window.onload = function(){
            function setarFullScreen(){
                var elem = document.body;
                requestFullScreen(elem);
                document.getElementById("click").style.display = "none";    
            }
            document.getElementById("click").addEventListener("click", setarFullScreen);
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="click">Clique aqui para maximizar</button>
    <div style="color: red;">teste</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Obs.: Via de regra, o usuário precisa aceitar primeiro a solicitação em tela cheia, e não é possível acioná-la automaticamente no pageload, ela precisa ser acionada por um usuário (como nesse exemplo, por um botão)